# Get data between two tags in Python

Tags: python, lxml, scrape

```
<h3>
<a href="article.jsp?tp=&arnumber=16">
Granular computing based
<span class="snippet">data</span>
<span class="snippet">mining</span>
in the views of rough set and fuzzy set
</a>
</h3>
```

Using Python I want to get the values from the anchor tag which should be Granular computing based data mining in the views of rough set and fuzzy set

I tried using lxml

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(html), parser)                   
xpath1 = "//h3/a/child::text() | //h3/a/span/child::text()"
rawResponse = tree.xpath(xpath1)              
print rawResponse
```

and getting the following output

```
['\r\n\t\t','\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tgranular computing based','data','mining','in the view of roughset and fuzzyset\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\]
```

Comment: Do you have to use `lxml`? Because I could probably think of a solution with `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `text_content` method:

```
import lxml.html as LH

html = '''<h3>
<a href="article.jsp?tp=&arnumber=16">
Granular computing based
<span class="snippet">data</span>
<span class="snippet">mining</span>
in the views of rough set and fuzzy set
</a>
</h3>'''

root = LH.fromstring(html)
for elt in root.xpath('//a'):
    print(elt.text_content())
```

yields

```
Granular computing based
data
mining
in the views of rough set and fuzzy set
```

or, to remove whitespace, you could use

```
print(' '.join(elt.text_content().split()))
```

to obtain

```
Granular computing based data mining in the views of rough set and fuzzy set
```

Here is another option which you might find useful:

```
print(' '.join([elt.strip() for elt in root.xpath('//a/descendant-or-self::text()')]))
```

yields

```
Granular computing based data  mining in the views of rough set and fuzzy set
```

(Note it leaves an extra space between `data` and `mining` however.)

`'//a/descendant-or-self::text()'` is a more generalized version of 
`"//a/child::text() | //a/span/child::text()"`. It will iterate through all children and grandchildren, etc.

Answer (score 1):

With [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = (the html you posted above)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> print " ".join(soup.h3.text.split())
Granular computing based data mining in the views of rough set and fuzzy set
```

Explanation:

`BeautifulSoup` parses the HTML, making it easily accessible. `soup.h3` accesses the `h3` tag in the HTML.

`.text`, simply, gets everything from the `h3` tag, excluding all the other tags such as the `span`s.

I use `split()` here to get rid of the excess whitespace and newlines, then `" ".join()` as the split function returns a list.