# lxml xhtml parsing producing characters instead of whitespaces

Tags: python, parsing, lxml, python-requests, removing-whitespace

I have been trying to parse what i believe is a xml page (Page's doctype header):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

... by using lxml's fromstring method. I end up getting the value I want, just with a bunch of '\r\n\t\t\t\t' characters surrounding it. Via self research, it seems this is due to the white space that is then parsed as these characters. However, i am also getting other characters as well as shown in the code below.

Some SO questions i've looked at that might make things faster:
[Get data between two tags in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758654/get-data-between-two-tags-in-python)
[Removing spaces and non-printable character in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795189/removing-spaces-and-non-printable-charcter-in-python)
[upper case html tags encoded in lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655586/upper-case-html-tags-encoded-in-lxml)

I have used the split() function which, when no argument is included, splits the string into substrings that were separated by one or more whitespace characters (i.e. effectively removing whitespace), but this only removes the '\r\n\t\t\t\t' characters. I have also tried lxml's text_content() method to the same end. I am wondering if there was a way to change the way the xml page is encoded when parsed with fromstring that will ignore white spaces (and anything else) and just return the text between the  tags. Anyway, find below my code and result (Requests code shortened for brevity):

---

```
from requests import session
from lxml import html


payload = {'Dictionary':'value'}
reqheaders = {'Dictionary':'value'}

c = session()
loginurl = 'URL'

response = c.post(loginurl, data = payload, headers = reqheaders)
a = response.content
b = html.fromstring(a)
value = b.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table[4]/tr[1]/td[1]/text()')    # list containing ['30,000\r\n\t\t\t\t Â\xa0\r\n\t\t\t\t  ']
k = value[0].split()  # Another list equal to ['30,000', 'Â']

>>>k[0]
'30,000'  #The value I need
```

This is the  element I am targeting from the xml page using the xpath (Sourced from response.content):

```
<TD title="Volume ahead: 140000" CLASS="DT   ">30,000\r\n\t\t\t\t \xc2\xa0\r\n\t\t\t\t  </TD>
```

and this is the raw source (from chrome) of the  element i am targeting (Spaces included):

```
<TD title="Volume ahead: 140000" CLASS="DT   ">30,000

              </TD>
```

It seems '\xc2\xa0' are the offending characters which pushes my thinking towards an encoding issue. Any advice on an efficient way to obtain this value directly without dealing with these anomalous characters would be great, preferably with as little processing time as possible.

Cheers,

p.s.: this is my current locale used in python 3.4.1:
('English_Australia', '1252')

any requests on question clarification, let me know. I'll answer with additional information ASAP.

Comment: @unutbu
Just tried lxml.etree and I got a traceback:
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Specification mandate value for attribute noWrap, line 17, column 81

Comment: `strip()` removes whitespaces characters, not `split()`

Comment: I made that comment because the explanation was incorrect: "split() function which, by default, removes white spaces if no other character is specified". However, your use of `split()` was actually correct (but should be explained as something like "splitting the string into words separated by one or more whitespace characters").

Comment: Thank you for clarifying isedev. Will edit question to reflect this.